# TBX and SpTBX: Components missing or renamed in SpTBX

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-xe4, sptbxlib

I am migrating my Delphi 7 code to Delphi XE4. In Delphi 7 code, `TBX` components are used. But for Delphi XE4, TBX components are changed to `SpTBX` (Now developed by SilverPoint) as per this link of stackoverflow

[Toolbar 2000 under Delphi XE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6266343/toolbar-2000-under-delphi-xe)

So, I downloaded and installed `SpTBX` for Delphi XE4. I think some controls are changed or renamed in `SpTBX`.

For example, in my Delphi 7 code, there was `TTBXDropDownItem` component in `TBX` packages, but it seems to be removed from `SpTBX` package. I have found `TSpTBXCombobox` in `SpTBX` but it does not have the properties which are present in `TTBXDropDownItem`.

```
Delphi 7 (TBX)

object myDropDown: TTBXDropDownItem
    Action = actZoom
    EditWidth = 60
    ShowImage = True
    AlwaysSelectFirst = False
    DropDownList = True
    LinkSubitems = mnuViewZoom
end

Delphi XE4 (SpTBX)

object myDropDown: TSpTBXCombobox

end
```

I just wanted to know whether `TSpTBXCombobox` is the replacement of `TTBXDropDownItem`? If yes, what are the similar properties which are used in `TTBXDropDownItem` in `TSpTBXCombobox` because I did not find `Action, EditWidth, ShowImage, AlwaysSelectFirst, DropDownList and LinkSubitems` in `TSpTBXCombobox`.

Comment: I guess you'll need to spend some time looking at the source code for both libraries and learning.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - I am looking at the link http://www.silverpointdevelopment.com/sptbxlib/releasehistory.htm It says "New toolbar item added, TSpTBXDropDownItem: a TTBXDropDownItem 
    descendant with unicode support." But I did not find this in Tool Palette.

Comment: I suggest that you read the source code to learn

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - I looked into the source code. In one file named SpTBXItem.pas, I found following comments: 20 November 2007 - version 1.9
  - New theme engine.
  - Added SpTBXHintWindowClass global variable, it specifies which
    THintWindow class is used to show the hints.
  - Added TSpTBXToolPalette and TSpTBXColorPalette items.
  - Added TSpTBXToolWindow component.
  - Removed TSpTBXComboBoxItem, TSpTBXDropDownItem, TSpTBXStringList
    and TSpTBXUndoList.    -------It clearly indicates that TSpTBXDropDownItem was removed on 20 November 2007

Comment: I think you need to read the code and not the comments

Comment: TBX and SpTBX components do have different names and (sometimes) different properties and events. In the [question you linked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6266343/toolbar-2000-under-delphi-xe) I wrote, "Some properties and events have changed or gone, which is annoying. I found I could generally figure out how to achieve the same thing pretty easily - it took a day or so to upgrade a large application for me - but you will find it's not a direct smooth transition." I don't have any specific advice beyond what I wrote in that answer.

Comment: It has been a long time since I used TBX and I don't know what `TTBXDropDownItem` is any more, so I don't know if `TSpTBXComboBox` is a replacement. I'd guess *not* because the names are usually similar. Perhaps you could include a screenshot of it so we can see what the component does / how it functions?

Comment: From the [SpTBX release notes](http://www.silverpointdevelopment.com/sptbxlib/releasehistory.htm) 23 December 2004: "New toolbar item added, TSpTBXDropDownItem: a TTBXDropDownItem descendant with unicode support." Then 20 November 2007: "Removed TSpTBXComboBoxItem, TSpTBXDropDownItem, ..." (same date TBX was removed.) My guess is you need to use `TSpTBXSubMenuItem` if you need a dropdown from a toolbar, a `TSpTBXComboBox` as you asked if you need something else. But these are *guesses*. Post a screenshot of your UI & what you want to accomplish, and we can help with what components to use now.